# How to delete all keys from an object in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, javascript-objects, react-typescript

I am trying to access the keys in an object which is of type `FilterType`

Here is the interface -

```
export interface FilterType {
  name?: string[];
  status?: string[];
  brand?: string[];
  categoryAndColour?: {
    [category: string]: string[];
  };
  rating?: string[];
}
```

Here is the object -

`const newState: FilterType = { ...state };`

I am trying to have a function which will remove all the keys from newState however whenever I try to map through the object or to a for..in I keep getting similar errors.

I am currently trying this -

```
for (var key in newState){
        delete newState[key];
      }
      return newState;
```

But I get the error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type`

And `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type`

How can I solve this?

Comment: _"I am trying to have a function which will remove all the keys from newState"_ - Why? What problem is this supposed to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to create a new empty state, just define the `newState` as a new object:

```
const newState: FilterType = {};
```

If you still want to delete all the keys anyway, define the type of `key` before using it in `for..in` ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=2&pln=15&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgMQQBtUoAVATzDwG8BYAKDjiUwFtgB%20ALjgGcYUZAHMA2gF0A3I2YDMMAK58e-QSInSmcAEZRMSACYqBQpGKky42ecGHQKAQUMBhCEQgKoK%20luajrqHZQFLwmIuKhamYalgC%20msx6MCLGUeaasYyM2BBIAqo2cAC8cDSxcJh8BMSklNSa2bn5SMAA7gDKMDa8hCRodXglNHAAdGNyqHDxWQxEwPAA1sAhcEsUEOjVfeRUwA0M6NBwABRriEgsbZ02AJQ%20zAbAc5MtHV2oomsWDJkMQA)):

```
let key: keyof FilterType;

for (key in newState){
  delete newState[key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Object.keys(newState).forEach((key) => delete newState[key]);
```

now, if you run:

```
console.log(newState)
```

the expected output will be an empty object:

```
{ }
```